# Why is this not reading what is in the file? Python

Tags: python

```
f = open("work.txt","a+")

a = input("number ")

print(a, "before file")

f.write(a)

contents = f.read()
print(contents)

f.close
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of the problem in your question even if it is the same as the title, not just code.

Answer (score 1):

The file is opened in append mode so the file pointer is at the end of the file when you attempt to read it. You should do a file seek to the beginning of the file if you intend to read the entire file after writing:

```
f = open("work.txt","a+")
a = input("number ")
print(a, "before file")
f.write(a)
f.seek(0)
contents = f.read()
print(contents)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`"a+"` opens the file in append/read mode, which means the file pointer is at the end of the file when first opened. The write appends to the file, but file pointer remains at the end after the write. You need to seek somewhere earlier in the file for `f.read` to return anything.